# Print segments for factor levels into stripchart in base R

Tags: r, for-loop, stripchart

I have a dataframe with a numerical variable and a factor variable, like this:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  numbers = c(rnorm(50, 3), runif(50)),
  levels = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace = T)
)
```

What I'd like to do is a stripchart that plots `df$numbers`against `df$levels` *and* inserts vertical segment lines representing the mean for each level.

```
stripchart(df$numbers ~ df$levels, method = "jitter")
```

Obviously, I could insert the means line for each level separately, e.g.:

```
segments(x0 = mean(df$numbers[df$levels=="A"]), y0 = 1-0.3, y1 = 1+0.3, col = "red" )
```

And so on for all other levels, which is tedious if you have multiple levels. So I've tried this `for`loop:

```
for(i in seq(unique(df$levels))){
  segments(x0 = mean(df$numbers[df$levels==i]),
           y0 = i - 0.3,
           y1 = i + 0.3,
           col = "red", lty = 3, lwd = 2)
}
```

But that doesn't print anything (and doesn't throw an error either). What's the cleanest and simplest code to insert the means segments?

Comment: I've tried this before; it produces an error: `Error in i - 0.3 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the 'levels' column is `factor`, use `levels` to get the levels of the `factor` 'un1', then loop over the sequence of unique elements, get the `mean` of the 'numbers' where the `levels` column is the unique value to create the `segments`

```
un1 <- levels(df$levels)
for(i in seq_along(un1)){
 segments(x0 = mean(df$numbers[df$levels==un1[i]]),
       y0 = i - 0.3,
       y1 = i + 0.3,
       col = "red", lty = 3, lwd = 2)
}
```

[image]

-checking the `mean`

```
with(df, tapply(numbers, levels, FUN = mean))
#      A        B        C        D        E 
#1.390202 1.541655 2.086605 2.377122 1.663159
```